# java mail api-not connect to smtp host

Tags: java, networking, jakarta-mail, connectexception

I am sending mail from our application. The properties used as follows,

```
"mail.smtp.auth", "true"
"mail.smtp.host", smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com
"mail.smtp.port", 587
```

We have two linux servers, my problem is that from one server it send mail, but from other server it not send mail. It throws exception as follows

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
        javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:219)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:81)
```

Comment: Did you try to open the port with other tool for example with `telnet` or `nc`?

Comment: @KARASZIIstván i have used nmap,  nmap -p 587 smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com and the o/p is Nmap scan report for smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com (106.10.149.91)
Host is up (0.094s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
587/tcp open  submission
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.49 seconds

Comment: @VishalKumbhar Take a look at this one: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t141237-send-smtp-mail-using-javamail-with-gmail-account.html

Comment: @KARASZIIstván how to use telnet or nc command

Comment: @VishalKumbhar >telnet smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com 587                    use this command add your ouput here

Comment: @Stranger telnet smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com 587
Trying 1.0.0.0...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: @Stranger but when type telnet command from other server it is connected to smtp server o/p is  telnet smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com 587
Trying 106.10.149.91...
Connected to smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp103.biz.mail.sg3.yahoo.com ESMTP

Comment: Looks like you have a firewall preventing you from accessing your mail server.  Try "ping" and "traceroute" to see where you're being blocked.

Comment: @Stranger actually i am confused, where is the actual problem, from link, it is said that change the smtp server settings. but my question from another server mails are sending properly. where to change the setting

Comment: @VishalKumbhar Try adding following property: "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" "true"

Comment: @RAS not working. still error connection timeout

Comment: The problem is with your server not with your library. If you're not able to connect with telnet then the port could not be open to the destination port. Contact with your sysadmin.

Comment: @VishalKumbhar Still are you facing the problem?

Comment: @VishalKumbhar As KARASZI said, have you contacted your system admin?

Comment: @RAS actually we dont have system admin. we manually do it. can you provide the steps how to do that?

Comment: @VishalKumbhar Do one thing. Follow this link & send a mail using telnet using thins link : http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html. Change port no. to 587 & send mail to any gmail account.

Comment: @RAS not able to open connection : telnet smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com 587
Trying 1.0.0.0...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out